# PayPal PHP Adaptive Paypal IPN Notification

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm currently using https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php to try to do a Delayed Chain Payment through Paypal , everything seems to work as intended but i realised the notify url doesn't seem to be triggering after the payment is authorised,hence i can't log the payment transaction details into db if the user doesn't go back to the return url.

```
$payRequest = new PayRequest(new RequestEnvelope("en_US"), 'PAY_PRIMARY', $this->input->post('cancel_return'), $this->input->post('currency_code'), $receiverList, $this->input->post('return').'?payKey=${payKey}');

$payRequest->ipnNotificationUrl = site_url('ipnlistener');
```

My ipnlistener currently just inserts a row of dummy data into the database, it seems to be working as intended when i access it manually. Any idea what might be the issue ? or any workarounds i could attempt ?

added payRequest data

> string(545)"requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&actionType=PAY_PRIMARY&cancelUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fweb%2Fclient%2Fmakepayment%2Frere¤cyCode=SGD&ipnNotificationUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fweb%2Fclient%2Ftesto&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=8934.26&receiverList.receiver(0).email=test%40hotmail.com&receiverList.receiver(0).primary=1&receiverList.receiver(1).amount=7344&receiverList.receiver(1).email=testtest%40hotmail.com&returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fweb%2Fclient%2Fmakepayment%2Frere%3FpayKey%3D%24%7BpayKey%7D"

Comment: Did you check your IPN history to see if it's showing that the IPNs are getting sent, and then if they show up make sure it's getting a 200 OK response?

Comment: Ok i just checked and it seems like it sent the IPN to the default notification url i set in the paypal sandbox acc. So it seems like ipnNotificationUrl setting doesn't seem to be registering in my proj, i'm working on my localhost, is it the reason why ?
  
    Notification URL
http://*removed*/
HTTP response code
200
Delivery status
Sent
No. of retries
0
Transaction ID
35926848R5329224K
IPN type
Transaction made

@Andrew Angell

Comment: That step in your code must not be doing what you think it is.  There should be a way to see the raw XML request getting generated and sent to PayPal.  Need to check that to see if it's getting included at all, and maybe getting included incorrectly.

Comment: Included the request data in my first post. Seems like the ipnNotificationUrl is included but doesn't have any effect. @Andrew Angell

Comment: That's not the raw request.  It should be an XML string.  Did you mask the value of the IPN URL here?

Comment: Ok i've updated the post with new data again. I tried to dig deeper into the code and seems like the request data got converted into the NVP format instead of the XML format. Let me know again if this is the raw request you're referring to. Apologies if i'm abit slow, I'm not very good with Paypal. Thanks so much! Yeap i masked the url as i'm not allowed to post links due to low reputation.  @Andrew Angell

Comment: Ok, yeah, so what I see in there is that your IPN URL seems to be using localhost..??  When PayPal sends a message to "localhost" that would be their own server.  You need to setup a domain that points to your localhost so you can something.whatever.com as your IPN URL.

Comment: Ok i used ngrok to setup a domain on my localhost, the other problem was the ipnlistener was in a controller that required login access, moved it out and everything works well now. Thanks @Andrew Angell